# Django + Angular6 + Jenkins + Docker + AWS Deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, angular6

**Versions**

- Angular 6
- Django version 2.1.2
- Python 2.7.12
- Angular CLI 6.1.0
- OS: linux x64
- Docker version 18.06.1-ce
- docker-compose version 1.21.2

**Dockerfile**

```
 FROM python:3.5
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Above are the versions and Docker files, we are using in our project. We deployed our project using Angular-6 with Django framework with the help of Jenkins and Docker in AWS server. We created a dist file of the Angular-6 project using (ng build) and then pasted that dist file inside our Django project.We used template to display the frontend structure.
We have given the static path like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

Are we are going in the right track or not please help if there are any other possible ways. Thank you..

Github link - https://github.com/p1212/Angular6_Django_Jenkins_Docker_AWS

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Whatever the process we are following whether it is correct or not.